# User.Identity.GetUserId() return null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Based on [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/20/building-a-simple-todo-application-with-asp-net-identity-and-associating-users-with-todoes.aspx) and the source code in github associated with this tutorial I am trying to implement a mvc application where users have individual resources.

I have the authorize attribute on my controller and if I am not logged in I will be redirected to the login page. I can see my user name on the top of the page so I assume things are fine. But then I try a create action on another controller and finds that currentUser is null.

This seem to happen in a random way which makes it very frustrating. But lately only failing.

Could it be something with creation of the database? I'm using Code First.

```
 [Authorize]
public class ShopsController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db;
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager;

    public ShopsController()
    {
        db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));

    }


    // GET: Shops
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        var shops = db.Shops.ToList().Where(shop => shop.Owner.Id == currentUser.Id);
        return View(shops);
    }
```

Comment: Hmm I wonder if your models are out of sync with the db. Do you get this when you've updated your entity models?

Comment: Also, why are you calling manager.FindById and returning the user entity if you're only going use the ID in next query? Seems like pointless db call...

Comment: I can usually get it to work by making sure i log out, close the solution, delete the database. I found out i was deleting the database every time in initiliazer. This i changed to DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges. About the other comment, have not thought about that, just using the sample code, get things to work, then hopefully understand it.

Answer (score 2):

try this code (Note: the cast to string):

```
 User.Identity.GetUserId<string>()
```

since my ID column in database was  **Id nvarchar(128),not null** without cast i was receiving null but after cast it was giving me the expected GUID